# Se puede usar datos que traigo de un componente y guardar los datos en un form reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Soy un poco nuevo en reactjs y necesito ayuda en este problema lo que sucede es que
tengo unos datos que vienen al ejecutar esta función desde otro componente

```
state = {
modalInsertar: false,
form: {
  id: "",
  Nombre: "",
  Descripcion: "",
  stock: "",
  categoria_id: "",
  created_at: "",
  updated_at: "",
},
```

};

```
modalActualizar = (dato) => {
console.log(dato);
this.setState({ form: dato, tipoModal: "" });
console.log(this.state.form);
this.modalInsertar();};
```

Cuando se ejecuta este método en la consola me depliga en la variable dato un array con el contenido es decir viene nombre, id , etc ,

pero yo quiero poner esos datos en form entonces según lo que entiendo es que para realizar esto se establece con setState y con eso ya deberían estar los datos que tengo en data en form  , pero no me esta regresando vacío como en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no se si me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema o explicarme por que me da vacío,

muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos, se necesita mas información para poder ayudarte, por ejemplo cual es la paridad entre los componentes, ya que para pasar datos desde un Componente padre al hijo se utiliza las props y entre hermanos generalmente utilizo callback

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando y el código estaba correcto, el problema era que setState es una promesa y al realizar console.log no mostraba nada, pero al hacer console log en otro lugar si se despliega correctamente la información del form.